# Rsquared in Sklearn Python VS MLmetrics R

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, regression

I have trained some regression models (Lasso, Random Forest and SVR). I tried to evaluate my results both in Python and R. In python Sklearn shows the Rsquared mathematical formula that uses, whereas the package MLmetrics in R does not show the formula used. Do you know where I can find this info? The results are different between the two languages and I would like to understand why. I am doing rolling training for my time series in python and then I evaluate my results using both python and R. Here are the differences for Rsquared for one month to 4 months ahead predictions -- for python: 0.136, 0.021, -0.164, -0.173 -- for R: 0.570, 0.536, 0.457, 0.450 . My intuition is that the mathematical formula for R gives values only between 0 and 1. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's the formula to calculate Rsq. It's pretty straightforward. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination . The fit will be different for python , R and even different packages within the same language

Comment: Can you provide the results of both? Would like to know  the difference...

Comment: @StupidWolf I guess there should be a mathematical formula, and that's why different packages/languages give different results. Otherwise, how can you explain the differences? Rsquared is a formula, and as all fomulas, it should give the same results. I guess Sklean and MLmetrics might have a small variation on the formulas they use.

Comment: @Ragnar I added the results. Thank you :)

Comment: @VickyVoukè, the r square is the same. see "As explained variance" tagged under the wiki page i pointed to. you have to look at the fitted values. They will be different for R and python.

Comment: @StupidWolf I only did the training using Sklearn in Python. Then, I save  my predictions and I use both sklearn rsquared in python and mlmetrics rsquared in r to evaluate my results. And the results are different. So, it does not seem to be the same.

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you a lot for your help. I saw your answer below, I also replied. I get negative values, both in sklearn and in MLmetrics in R. Only caret rsquared in R does not give me negative values. Indeed the values of R above correspond to caret and not MLmetrics as I initially wrote (sorry for this). Please look on my answers below your post. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: the caret approach does not hold with negative Rsquared, which is possible when your model overfits

Comment: @StupidWolf thanks for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To long to type as a comment, both calculations are correct,

from [mlmetrics](https://github.com/yanyachen/MLmetrics/blob/master/R/Regression.R):

```
R2_Score <- function(y_pred, y_true) {
  R2_Score <- 1 - sum((y_true - y_pred)^2) / sum((y_true - mean(y_true))^2)
  return(R2_Score)
}

y_true = c(3, -0.5, 2, 7)
y_pred = c(2.5, 0.0, 2, 8)

R2_Score(y_pred,y_true)
[1] 0.94860816
```

from [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L499)

```
numerator = (weight * (y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum(axis=0,
                                                      dtype=np.float64)
denominator = (weight * (y_true - np.average(
        y_true, axis=0, weights=sample_weight)) ** 2).sum(axis=0,
                                                          dtype=np.float64)
nonzero_denominator = denominator != 0
nonzero_numerator = numerator != 0
valid_score = nonzero_denominator & nonzero_numerator
output_scores = np.ones([y_true.shape[2]])
output_scores[valid_score] = 1 - (numerator[valid_score] /
                                      denominator[valid_score])
```

If we run it:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

0.9486081370449679
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. Thank you. I now confirmed with my code. I have used the R2 caret and this produces different results. I recovered this code l wrote long time ago, so I am sorry for the confusion. So the problem is caret rsquared. I see that there is someone else having the same problem here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230913/how-caret-calculates-r-squared. So what does caret r squared produces, I am not sure I understand.

Comment: One more info: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-calculate-r-squared-with-numpy-in-python .  The python code used in this link, which limits the Rsquared between 0 and 1, gives exactly the same results as caret rsquared in R.

Comment: caret uses the square of the correlation because the rsquared would be the square of the pearson correlation coefficient. However, when there's something wrong with your model, this does not hold. Use the R squared from these above.. I would recommend that